# Entity Framework and self-referencing collections

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to model a location object. Locations can ship to many other locations and receive from many locations. Locations also optionally have a parent location. How do I represent this in my database via Entity Framework?
This is what I have so far:
Location Class:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public Location ParentLocation { get; set; }

    public int? ParentLocationId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Location> ShipToLocations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Location> ReceiveFromLocations { get; set; }
    
}
```

OnModelCreating function in my DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Location>(entity =>
   {
       entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
       entity.HasOne(x => x.ParentLocation);
       entity.HasMany(x => x.ShipToLocations);
       entity.HasMany(x => x.ReceiveFromLocations);
    });
}
```

I seem to be getting a ParentLocationId field in by database, which makes sense to me.
However, ef also generates LocationId and LocationId1 fields for the database which makes no sense. The way I understand it, Entity Framework SHOULD be generating join tables of some kind because locations each have MANY ship to locations and MANY receive from locations, all of which are other locations.

Comment: TLDR; `.HasOne(x => x.ParentLocation).WithMany()` & `.HasMany(x => x.ShipToLocations).WithMany(x => x.ReceiveFromLocations)` .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried to make this with a single table, EF tried to create additional foreign keys for destination and source location. You can't actually achieve that with a single table. You should have an additional table, representing the   destinations available to the location.

You should try structuring your classes like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other fields here
    
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Location Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Location> ChildLocations { get; } 
    
    public ICollection<LocationDestintaion> Destinations { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<LocationDestintaion> Sources { get; set; }
}

public class LocationDestintaion
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public Location Source { get; set; }
    
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public Location Destination { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would have this kind of `ModelBuilder` configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Parent).WithMany(x => x.ChildLocations)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId).IsRequired(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Destinations).WithOne(x => x.Source)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.SourceId);
        
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Sources).WithOne(x => x.Destination)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DestinationId);

modelBuilder.Entity<LocationDestintaion>().ToTable("Paths")
            .HasKey(x => new {x.SourceId, x.DestinationId});
```

You can then query destinations and sources  like this:

```
const int locationId = 1;

var availableDestinations = context.Locations.Where(x => x.Id == locationId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Destinations).ToList();

var sourceLocations = context.Locations.Where(x => x.Id == locationId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Sources).ToList();
```